# Camera Preview inside Window with iPhone

Tags: iphone

I can launch a camera capture with UIImagePicker but capture process is done in another view. Is it possible to 'embed' camera preview into the application window?

What I use is:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker;
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.allowsImageEditing = YES;
picker.delegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you can come is to add a cameraOverlayView to the camera view and put a 'frame' around the picture. However, this will crop, rather than scale, the viewfinder.

Comment: just to clarify, does this need os 3.1? and if i get screenshot with this, can i get camera's preview? or just the 'frame' and a blank rectangle?

Comment: Yes, this requires 3.1, and if you use UIGetScreenImage(), I believe you'll get the whole screen, camera view + overlay.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the preview as a subview like this:

```
[self.view addSubview:picker.view];
[picker viewWillAppear:YES];
[picker viewDidAppear:YES];
```